# Random com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found error

Tags: google-bigquery

I run around 10-15 queries using Bigquery Java api on a daily basis. Most of them create tables using files existing in CloudStorage. Every now and then (1-2 queries every other day) randomly generate the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
```

If I run the same queries again, they may run fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have failed job Id?

Comment: Are you getting this error in the job's error result, or do you get this while polling for job completion?

Comment: Polling for job's completion. I'm waiting for this to reoccur (can't run it over a weekend) to send you a job ID.

Comment: Here's a job that failed:job_7V-cbfRvtPcY6797YVBALolGHGw

{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)

Answer (score 0):

It is about 9 year since the questions was originally asked but for the benefit of anyone else who might face this like I did

"If the underlying files for one of the tables get updated to a new version while the query is still running, then the query might fail with this error"

For me it is something like

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Files gs://<filepath>(Version 1703943413405082)",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Files gs://<filepath>(Version 1703943413405082)",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```